# Create a spike test in Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

Just starting to use Gatling and have a requirement to conduct a Spike Test. I'm trying to work out how to do it as I cant find a way to ramp down users afterwards.

I am looking to do something like -

```
setUp(
    scn.inject(
      atOnceUsers(100),
      nothingFor(20 minutes), //think this should hold a flat load for 20 minutes
      rampUsers(900) over (60 seconds) // ramps 900 users over 60 secs,
      //need something to drop the load back to original state
    )
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

My alternate thought is to use 2 scenario groups and have the flat load run, have the second to do nothing for 20 minutes and just spike up, do its thing and finish, leaving the initial group to finish.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to play with the [example of throttling in the docs](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/simulation_setup/#throttling)?

```
setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(100) during (30 minutes))).throttle(
    reachRps(100) in (10 seconds),
    holdFor(1 minute),
    jumpToRps(50),
    holdFor(2 hours)
)
```

I haven't used it myself, but using `reachRps` could work for you. I'm trying to outline your scenario so you get the idea:

```
setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(100) during (30 minutes))).throttle(
    reachRps(100) in (10 seconds),
    holdFor(20 minutes),
    reachRps(900) in (60 seconds), //ramp up
    holdFor(1 minute),
    reachRps(100) in (60 seconds), //ramp down again
    holdFor(20 minutes)
)
```

This is just an outline and you'll definitly have to tweak the `constantUsersPerSec` for your usecase, see the docs on this:

> You still have to inject users at the scenario level. Throttling tries
>   to ensure a targeted throughput with the given scenarios and their
>   injection profiles (number of users and duration). It’s a bottleneck,
>   ie an upper limit. If you don’t provide enough users, you won’t reach
>   the throttle. If your injection lasts less than the throttle, your
>   simulation will simply stop when all the users are done. If your
>   injection lasts longer than the throttle, the simulation will stop at
>   the end of the throttle.

Comment: I didn't have a look at throttling. I decided to simply create 2 execution groups and that seemed to work nicely.